# How do I change the compiler that VSCode uses to compile c++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

My VScode uses the old wrong compiler path, that i already deleted when i try to compile my c++ code. It then shows the error.
`Build finished with error(s).

- The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
  `
  vscode console recognizes commands such as g++ --version and shows the right new version. How do i run the code with the new compiler?

I tried going to changing configuration(UI) and choosing the new path to the compiler, but it doesn't work I guess

Comment: Have you updated your `tasks.json` file?

Comment: Show us your configuration files.

Comment: there are some very good webpages that show you how to do it. They are called the VSC C++ doc pages